# A specific Jensen's inequality for a proof

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, radicals, jensen-inequality

It's related to this [Inequality : $\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{2}a^2b}{2a+b} \leq \sum_{cyc} \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2ab+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585246/inequality-sum-cyc-frac-sqrt2a2b2ab-leq-sum-cyc-frac-sqrta) more particulary to this passage :

*Please suggest how to show that
$ \sqrt{2} \leq \displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2ab+1}$*

My try

There is a simple method ,you can minimize each term like this but first you have:
$$\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2ab+1}$$
We can rewrite the expression like this :
$$\frac{\sqrt{(a+b)^2-2ab}}{2ab+1}$$
Now the idea is to remark that for a fixed sum of two numbers the product of this two numbers is maximal when each term is equal .

Here we use this method and remark  that this method minimize the numerator and maximize the denominator so we have :

$a+b=x$ and $ab=0.25x^2$

$c+b=y$ and $bc=0.25y^2$

$a+c=z$ and $ac=0.25z^2$

We get :

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-0.5x^2}}{0.5x^2+1}+\frac{\sqrt{y^2-0.5y^2}}{0.5y^2+1}+\frac{\sqrt{z^2-0.5z^2}}{0.5z^2+1}$$

So we have to prove :

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-0.5x^2}}{0.5x^2+1}+\frac{\sqrt{y^2-0.5y^2}}{0.5y^2+1}+\frac{\sqrt{z^2-0.5z^2}}{0.5z^2+1}\geq \sqrt{2}$$

But I can't use directly Jensen because the function $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-0.5x^2}}{0.5x^2+1}$ is not convex so my question is :

> 1)What's the kind of function $f(x)$ is ?
>
> 2)What's the specific Jensen's inequality we have to use ?

Thanks a lot .

Comment: this inequality was proved already in this forum

Comment: Yes but I'm interested by a new proof .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your reasoning is total wrong.

It remains to prove that
$$\sum\frac{a+b}{\frac{(a+b)^2}{2}+1}\geq2,$$ which is wrong for $c=3$ and $a=b\rightarrow0^+.$

I have a proof of your starting inequality by full expanding, by BW, by uvw and by SOS (which you saw).

Which way do you prefer?

Comment: I vote for SOS.

Comment: My reasoning is wright you have forgotten the condition $x+y+z=6$.You can check with wolfram alpha that the inequality with separate variables is true . https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=extrema+sqrt(0.5x%C2%B2)%2F(0.5x%C2%B2%2B1)%2Bsqrt(0.5y%C2%B2)%2F(0.5y%C2%B2%2B1)%2Bsqrt(0.5z%C2%B2)%2F(0.5z%C2%B2%2B1)+with+x%2By%2Bz%3D6

Comment: Your WA is wrong! Try $x=y\rightarrow0^+$ and $z=6$.

Comment: @clark See my proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585246

Comment: You can't have $x=0$ and $y=0$ and finally $z=6$ it implies that we have $a=0=3$ or $c=0=3$

Comment: @FatsWallers Try $x=0$ and $y=z=3.$

Comment: @FatsWallers there appears to be a bug with your wolframalpha link, as it says the both max and min is $1.41421$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks! Always a pleasure reading your posts.

Comment: In fact Michael Rozenberg you can't cut my method to have just $a+b$ or $ab$ .Your last counter-example fails because we have $ab=bc=ca=0$ and $a+b=0$ and finally $c=3$ it give : $$2\sqrt{3^2}\geq \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Check your computations again and see please better my post.

Comment: In fact this is my fault .I don't mentioned an implicit condition this is it : $$2(a+b+c)=2(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{cb}+\sqrt{ac})=6$$ . Now it would be right...

Comment: If you say that $a+b=2\sqrt{ab}$ then $a=b$, but you need to prove the starting inequality for all positives $a$, $b$ and $c$ such tat $a+b+c=3$.

Comment: Thanks to you ! I understand now my mistake we have in fact : $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-0.5x^2}}{0.5x^2+1}+\frac{\sqrt{y^2-0.5y^2}}{0.5y^2+1}+\frac{\sqrt{z^2-0.5z^2}}{0.5z^2+1}\leq \sqrt{2}$$
with the same condition on $x,y,z$ .

Comment: Yes, of course!