# A difficult generalization of an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

it's related to my OP here [A specific Jensen's inequality for a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586889/a-specific-jensens-inequality-for-a-proof/2586925?noredirect=1#comment5340820_2586925)

We have for $a+b+c=3$ where $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers

$ \sqrt{2} \leq \displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2ab+1}$

Michael Rozenberg have proved this with elegance .

So I was wondering if there exists a generalization to this (with the same condition) and we have :

$$ \frac{3\sqrt{\alpha}\sqrt{2}}{2\beta +1} \leq \displaystyle\sum_{{a,b,c}} \frac{\sqrt{\alpha(a^2+b^2)}}{2\beta ab+1}$$

The sum above is cyclic.$\alpha,\beta$ are positive real numbers .

I have no idea to prove this and I get this with my method related to my previous OP .

Thanks a lot .

Comment: I have a proof for all $\beta\geq\frac{1}{18}$ and $\beta=0$.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg can you tell me if the minimum of :$$\frac{(2ab+1)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+ \frac{(2cb+1)}{\sqrt{c^2+b^2}}+ \frac{(2ac+1)}{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}$$ is easier to calculate ? If yes I have a full proof .Thanks a lot.

Comment: For positives $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $a+b+c=3$?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot the condition wich is the same .

Comment: I see that it's not $\frac{9}{\sqrt2}.$

Comment: Thanks so it's my answer $\frac{9}{\sqrt{2}}$ ?

Comment: No! The answer another number.